# What is the maximum data size?

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, pickle

I use pickle to serialize data in python 3. At one point, the script stopped working for me because the .pickle file was broken. I want to know if there is a limit on the size of the data that pickle can serialize.

Comment: What does *broken* mean specifically? And how much data are you trying to serialize?

Comment: Error: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte in position 1
Size of file is 91 kB

Comment: That information should be in your post body. The issue isn't that the data size is too large; it's that it's not recognizing non-ASCII values. That error message is what your post should be asking about instead.

Comment: The problem is that the script worked for a month and everything broke just now, so it seems to me that the matter is not in the encoding (serialization occurs in byte form)

Comment: And what it seems to you is incorrect. This is an encoding issue, not a data size issue. You've added something that is encoded incorrectly to the file, and it can't be read back properly. The content of the error message tells you that specifically, whether you want to ignore it or not.

Comment: All that i want to know: what limit of serializing data size for pickle

Comment: I would be willing to bet you a week's pay that it's much greater than 91 kB. The question you're asking is irrelevant to the problem you're experiencing. Wasting time on information that is meaningless will not solve that problem.